# Window Azure Emulator: Roles instances are taking longer than expected to start

Tags: azure, emulation

I've just created a very simple window azure project with a web application. When I press 'Ctrl+F5' to deploy it to azure emulator, it keeps getting the message:
Roles instances are taking longer than expected to start. Do you want continue to waiting?

I've checked the dfagent.log file showing:

```
[2013/06/24, 16:16:35.532,  INFO, 00008500] DFAgent host address: 
[2013/06/24, 16:16:39.849, ERROR, 00010496] Failed to read pipe.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:39.849, ERROR, 00012032] Failed to read pipe.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:39.853, ERROR, 00010496] RuntimepPipeClientThread=0x8007006d
[2013/06/24, 16:16:39.997, ERROR, 00001176] Failed to read pipe.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:39.998, ERROR, 00008392] Failed to read pipe.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.306, ERROR, 00005136] Failed to read pipe.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.313, ERROR, 00005136] RuntimepPipeClientThread=0x8007006d
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.322,  INFO, 00012036] Called`enter code here` GetState
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.322,  INFO, 00012036] There are 0 notifications.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.322,  INFO, 00012036] There are 0 completion events.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.322,  INFO, 00012036] GetState returned.
[2013/06/24, 16:16:40.806, ERROR, 00008440] Failed to read pipe.
```

I've checked all the process and found no conflicted process running.
Did restart computer, re-install emulator and checking all similar questions on stackoverflow as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [this blog post](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/11/28/net-tcp-and-dfagent-amongst-other-things/) about port 808 and DFAgent?

> The net.tcp  binding uses  port 808. If your web roles hang and your
>   debugger can’t attach but the roles are not being recycled then the
>   cause may be because you already have a binding to this port.
>
> It’s important to understand that the role instances and dfagent, the
>   diagnostics monitor, uses this port to chatter.